# Haskell Cabal/Stackのパッケージをデバッグする良い設定がわからない。

Tags: haskell

HaskellのYesodというウェブフレームワークの改造をしたいと思っています。
YesodはGitHub上で開発が行われています。

https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod

HackageにあるYesodを利用する場合はStackで依存を記述したりテンプレートを用いれば良いのですが、ローカル環境で手を加えたYesodをStackプロジェクトに参照させる方法がわかりません。

ローカル環境のYesodをテスト用のStackプロジェクトに参照させてテストしながら開発がしたいです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

テストをするためのStackプロジェクトの `stack.yaml` に以下を記述すればローカルのYesodを依存パッケージとして利用することができました。

```
packages:
- '.'
- '/Yesodのリポジトリまでのパス/yesod/yesod-core/'
```